# Situations in which interchanging the order of integration fail.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, soft-question, physics

Suppose that our underlying space is $\Bbb R^2$ and $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, for concreteness. It is not hard to artificially construct such a function $f$ such that 
$$
\int_Y\int_X f(x,y)dxdy\ne \int_X\int_Y f(x,y)dydx
$$
,i.e. the interchanging of the order of integration in not applicable. Note that Fubini's Theorem implies that any $f$ with the above property is not absolutely integrable on $\Bbb R^2$.

Although we, the mathematicians, are quite cautious about this matter, it seems to me that many physicists don't really pay much attention to the problem at all. I was trying to convinced my physicist friend that this is a serious matter but failed. The function I gave as an example seem too ad hoc for him. I want a more real-life example.

Is there any $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ that arises naturally from a physical situation such that the interchanging the order of integration fail? I want the function $f$ to be in a classical sense i.e. not a distribution or any generalized function.

Comment: The integrand must suffer a discontinuity for the interchange to fail on a bounded region.  On an unbounded region, the interchange may fail for a continuous integrand, but it is an artifact of the conditional convergence of the iterated integrals.  As you point out, absolute integrability permits the interchange.  Hence, the failure of the interchange is a consequence of some "accidental cancellation at infinity" as mentioned by Korner in the book Fourier Analysis.  I suspect this is rare in physical situations. An infinite region itself is an unphysical paradigm.

Comment: I believe you're mostly right. Though I think physicists don't have that much difficultly accepting infinite region, looking at how they welcome Dirac delta so warmly as a "function".

Comment: This is a good question which might get some response on the Physics SE site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266784/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3566631/321264

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$ for $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{2 x}{(x+y)^3}-\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\right) \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac1{(1+x)^2}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac12,
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^1-\frac1{(1+y)^2} \ \mathsf dy\\
&= -\frac12.
\end{align}
Here $f$ does not satisfy the assumptions of Fubini's theorem since $|f|$ is not integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What physical situation does this $f$ comes from?

Comment: Though I agree that this look natural enough, whatever that means :)