# Example of unequal iterated integral but that does not contradict Fubini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Consider counting measure $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ on $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$

Define a function,
$$
f(x,y) = 2-2^{-x} \ \text{if} \ \  x=y \\
\text{and}\\ f(x,y) = -2 + 2^{-x} \ \text{if} \ \ x=y+1
$$
I showed that
$$
\int_X(\int_Y f(x,y)d\mu_2)d\mu_1 =1
$$
and
$$
\int_Y(\int_X f(x,y)d\mu_1)d\mu_2 =-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore two iterated integral does not equal.
But I can to show that why Fubini's theorem does not contradict.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int |f(x,y)| d\mu_1(y) d\mu_2(x) \geq \int |2-2^{x}| d\mu_1(x)=\sum_x |2-2^{x}| =\infty$. Hence $f$ is not integrable on the product. Neither is it non-negative. So Fubini/Tonelli Theorem is not applicable.

[$ \sum |2-2^{x}| \geq \sum 2 -\sum 2^{-x} =
\infty$ since $\sum 2^{-x} <\infty$].

Comment: Yeah... But my point is why fubini's theorem doesn't contradict..... I think... Since fubini's theorem not applicable here(as you showed)...Vacuously it doesn't contradict fubini's theorem.. am I correct?

Comment: Yes. If the hypothesis of the theorem is not satisfied, there is no contradiction.  @annie_lee